# Custom command to create and open multiple files in terminal

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal, command-line-arguments

I'm wondering if there is a way to create and open multiple files in terminal using a custom one-liner terminal command using OSX 10.9.4.

like `$ makemore test.rb test2.rb`

then it opens using my default Sublime Text3

I found the custom command to create and open a single file.

```
lazy()
{
touch $1
open $1
}
```

Is this possible to make something that makes, then opens multiple files?

> P.S. Thanks to this Stackoverflow question for how to make custom command to create and open a single file. [How can I create and open a file from terminal with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584704/how-can-i-create-and-open-a-file-from-terminal-with-a-single-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lazy() { for x; do touch "$x"; open "$x"; done; }
```

Then call it with a list of file names.

Comment: You have any idea how amazing you are! Thank you so much!!

I can't up vote you as I don't have enough rep yet.