# How to create and open file in one command (Mac terminal)?

Tags: macos, terminal, command, touch

What is the one line equivelant of:
1. touch example.txt
2. open example.txt

I've tried a number of piping commands but I can't get it working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create and open a file from terminal with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584704/how-can-i-create-and-open-a-file-from-terminal-with-a-single-command)

Answer (score 0):

Just put a semicolon between the two commands on the same line:

```
touch example.txt; open example.txt
```

Comment: Assign the name to a variable and use that:

n='example.txt'; touch $n; open $n